# return false on dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, delegates, live

I'm trying to prevent an event on dynamically created elements.
I tried several ways but none worked.

On deafult, a click on the div containing the class opens a menu, and I want to disable that.
This is my code (please note I'm using jQuery 1.6.4 so I'm not able to use the "on" method).

```
    $(function() {
    $( document ).delegate( "span.highlight_mkt", "click", function() {
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

I have tried this using the "live" method as well but without any success.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the block definitely getting fired? Tried adding a breakpoint?

Comment: It's fired, if i'm adding an alert it will pop.
But it won't stop the bubbling.

Comment: Can you give us your html and dynamically loaded html?

Comment: Can you also show the code from the bubbled event? How is that attached?

Comment: Well its an old code from a diffrent developer that worked here, and it's not even in jQuery. please note that using a regular "return false" on the item works, but not if its dynamically created.

Comment: Hi, are you add elements after the delegate call?

Comment: It does add content but as I know the return false / stopPropgation / preventDefault should work.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this link helps you -> [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$(document).delegate("span.highlight_mkt", "click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* your code here */
});
```

**EDIT**

you tried this too?

```
$('span.highlight_mkt').live("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /* your code here */
});
```

Comment: try this with "live" again

Comment: Tried it with "live" too, no success.

Comment: and $('span.highlight_mkt').unbind('click'); ?!

Answer (score 0):

This one should stops the event propagation:

```
   $(function() {
    $( document ).delegate( "span.highlight_mkt", "click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is you have span with highlight_mkt class in your html form with click event attached using selector or document. And you are loading using Ajax or dynamically creating other span with same class name.

So in order to prevent events on your dynamically created elements you can use [**.die()**](http://api.jquery.com/die/) function with container name where you are attaching dynamically created elements as following:

```
$('container_selector span.highligh_mkt').die('click');
```

In this method click event will be fired only your elements which is not attached dynamically. 
If I understand you incorrectly please clarify your question.

What you did is you are attached event handler to `document` element or global container using .live() jquery function. So it is not good thing to do. I will explain later.

```
$('body').live('click','span.hihligh_mkt', function(e){
//Your code here. Which is doing some cool staff i believe :)
});
```

However if you want to prevent only for dynamically created elements do following:

```
$('body').live('click', 'span.some_class', function(e){

    // This part is needed in order to check weather it is attached dynamically
    // or it is predefined html objects
    if($(e.target).closest('#some_container').length==0)
    {
      //Your code here. Which is doing some cool staff i believe :) 
    }
});
```

So in above you will just check, does event fairing element is dynamically attached to container element or it is part original html. Of course this kind of  method can be avoided if you will use event which will be attached individually to the the elements like following when DOM ready.

```
$('span.hihligh_mkt').live('click', funtion(e){});
```

In this case only elements which was exists in DOM ready will get handlers. Other dynamically attached elements will not have event handlers. Unless you are not doing deep cloning of span elements.

Another thing is here when you attaching event handler to body or other root elements it gives you slow performance. You can read about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

> **Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events**
>   take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled.

**[You can see some example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/E5Guc/)**

Comment: You understood my question perfectly, but this won't work as well.

Comment: Ok. How many elements you have and how you are attaching to click event? I mean what kind of selector you are using? So if you clarify it I think I really can help you.

Comment: I update my answer. I guess I predict correctly what you did. So, I did my best to answer your question. I hope it will help you to understand.