# jQuery $(this) reference difference between .live() and .on() event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today, I try to answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899136/return-false-on-dynamically-created-element/20899376#20899376). So, the person how asked question uses jQuery 1.6 for some reason (I have never used this version by myself before). However i knew  about **[.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** event attachment with data option from documentation, which was deprecated in 1.7. So, when i used `$(this)` inside of event handling function it returns selector object not data object.

So I created two test file here, one in jQuery 1.6.4 and other in 1.10.1 as following.

**Jquery 1.6.4**

```
$('body').live('click', 'span.some_class', function(e){
    console.log($(this))
});
```

**Jquery 1.10.1**

```
$('body').on('click', 'span.some_class', function(e){
   console.log($(this));
});
```

In [first case](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/QMn5x/2/) i got following output:

```
[body, context: body, constructor: ....
```

In [second case](http://jsfiddle.net/Antindexer/6yPxV/1/) i got following output:

```
[span.some_class, context: ......
```

So, I have question, Why output is different? Can someone give me explanation who have historical knowledge on this?. 
Because it can be really useful to my to help to others when they ask me question related to jQuery 1.6.4.

> **Edit:** So i understand what I did wrong here is I messed .live() with .on() which is not equivalent in newer version of jQuery. So
>   .on() is equivalent to .delegate() in 1.6.4 and live() equivalent to
>   bind(). **Sorry for** my question. I did not read documentation carefully.

Comment: your syntax for live is not correct, at least not as you expect it to be

Comment: @A.Wolff Can you point it out please? I really want to understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Should be more like `$('span.some_class').live('click', function(e){ ...`. Your version will bind the event to `body` instead of `span.some_class`

Comment: @Phoenix second (optional) argument for live is a data object, not a string selector. `.live( events, data, handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: live() vs delegate()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204316/jquery-live-vs-delegate)

Comment: @Phoenix - As AWolff pointed out, the second optional arg isn't a selector. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Phoenix no, the sig method is different, check the DOC. Live is similar to bind but for element present or not in DOM at time of processing binding code. In fact, live uses document level to bind event

Comment: @A.Wolff thank you I understand what is wrong here. Should I delete my question? Because people giving me minus points for not reason. I did not understand first what i did wrong. Now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `live` and `on` is that `live` is attached directly to the element and `on` is delegated to the element. `on()` was introduced to simplify all kind of jQuery bindings (also `bind()` and `delegate()`).

Consider the following html:

```
<div class="foo">
     <div class="bar">
     </div>
</div>
```

And this jQuery-bindings:

```
//live() checks the whole DOM on every change, could get very slow 
$(".bar").live("click",...);

//on() only has to check a part of the DOM on changes
$(".foo").on("click",".bar",...);
```

**And, why is your console output wrong?**

You're not using live correct. It must be: `$('span.some_class').live('click', function(e){... });`
The second parameter is just to parse additional data.